# Is there a way to compare DDMMYYYY format date with current date?

Tags: mainframe, dfsort

I have a requirement to get today's transactions into a separate file through JCL SORT. The date format that I have is in DDMMYYYY format.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you show a bit of code and further explain what you have tried?

Comment: Hi Jnovack, I have written a SORT step, SORT FIELDS=COPY INCLUDE COND=(20,10,CH,EQ,DATE1), the date from position 20 in the input file is in the format DDMMYYYY. Because of which I am not getting the expected output. I wanted to know the way this SORT card can be modified so that I can get current days transactions in the output file.

Comment: Are you using Syncsort or DFSort?

Comment: I am using DFSort

Comment: I suggest removing the JCL tag as this is not a JCL question and add the DFSORT tag as this is a DFSort question.

Answer (score 1):

> INCLUDE COND=(20,10,CH,EQ,DATE1), Will not work because DATE1 returns the date in C'yyyymmdd'format

Try reformatting the date in input file and then compare it with DATE1. Refer below SORT CARD

```
----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+-
//SORTIN DD *                             
DATA1               01102020              
DATA2               07102020              
DATA3               07102020              
DATA4               01092020              
DATA5               01102010              
DATA6               01102019              
/*                                        
//SORTOUT DD SYSOUT=*                     
//SYSIN  DD *                             
 OPTION COPY                              
 INREC BUILD=(1,28,X,25,4,23,2,21,2)      
 OUTFIL REMOVECC,                         
 BUILD=(1,28),INCLUDE=(30,08,CH,EQ,DATE1) 
/*
```

Output will be:

```
DATE2               07102020 
DATE3               07102020
```